# Error CS0311 deriving an ordered tree from a tree

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance

I am attempting to create a class `MyOrderedTree`, derived from a base class `MyTree` thus...

```
public class MyTree<T>
{
    public T                 Payload  { get; private set; }
    public MyTree<T>         Parent   { get; private set; }
    public MyList<MyTree<T>> Children { get; private set; }

    // Works
}
```

and

```
public class MyOrderedTree<T> : MyTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public new MyOrderedList<MyOrderedTree<T>> Children {  get; private set; }   // Error CS0311

    private MyOrderedTree()
    {

    }

    public MyOrderedTree(T passed_payload) : base (passed_payload)
    {
        Children = new MyOrderedList<MyOrderedTree<T>>();                        // Error CS0311
    }

    // Works

}
```

The list class is defined....

```
public class MyList<T>
{
    // Works
}
```

from which I have derived...

```
public class MyOrderedList<T> : MyList<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    // Works
}
```

The problem with this is that it produces this error:

```
CS0311 The type 'MyOrderedTree<T>' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 
'MyOrderedList<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'MyOrderedTree<T>' to 
'System.IComparable<MyOrderedTree<T>>'.
```

where I have marked in the listing, and I don't know what to do about it.

What should I do to correct this? Or, if this is not the right way to go about what I am attempting, what should I do in preference?

Comment: `MyOrderedTree<T>` is not `IComparable<T>`, only `T` is. In other words, you have not told the compiler how you want `MyOrderedTree<T>` to be compared. You may want some code to loop through the tree and compare it with another similar tree. By the way, `MyOrderedTree.Children` does not override `MyTree.Children`, it just hides it

Comment: Care with `public new MyOrderedList<MyOrderedTree<T>> Children`. This mask `base.Children`,  no override.

Comment: @Charlieface, I see what you mean. It thinks I want to order the lists based on some property of the list, which I haven't provided for, but I don't, I want to order the lists based on some property of the elements in the lists, but there is no way to establish that (that I can see, anyway). I'm having trouble expressing what I mean here, which is usually a symptom of a design problem. Oh well, I guess I'll just have to write `MySortedTree` as a separate class. Thanks for the help, anyway. (The hiding part was intentional, thanks.)

Comment: You could declare it `public class MyOrderedTree<T> : MyTree<T>, IComparable<MyOrderedTree<T>> where T : IComparable<T>` then imlement `Compare` method doing some kind of comparison on the list

Comment: @Charlieface righto. I'll try that tomorrow.